# Rows in Excel VBA Macros

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, macros, vba

I need help in being able to do the following:

- In Worksheet A I have raw data.
- In Worksheet B I have a template with formulas.
- The data on Worksheet A change on a weekly basis.

I need to find a way to select the raw data from Worksheet A and insert it in Workbook B. The formulas of Workbook B are at the right of where raw data should be entered and also down at the end of the raw data. Clearly my problem is that I have totals and the number of rows of raw data change.

Comment: Can you post in what you've tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

There's a myriad of ways for doing this.  I prefer to figure out how many rows I'm working with (i.e., where the data ends) and then set up my ranges based on those numbers.  Determining the last row or column can also be done several ways as evidenced by several sites, including [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm) and [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/td0058.html).  The way I do it is

```
lngLastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lngLastCol = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
```

Once you know the last row/column, you can subtract for however many total rows you need, etc.